# Matlab `mcc`: All m-files to include when compiling executable?

Tags: matlab, mcc

I have a Matlab script `go.m` that creates custom objects and runs
a suite of simulations.  There is interest in porting it to
a different network where the Matlab licenses are few. Our
strategy is to compile the script into a stand-alone *.exe
so that it can run without using up licenses.  Once I figure
out all the ropes, the Matlab Compiler Runtime will be installed
on the target system.

I managed to use command-line `mcc` to compile the TMW online example,
[magicsquare](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/create-and-install-a-standalone-application-from-matlab-code.html).
Using `cygwin`'s bash:

```
$ cd ~/bin
$ ln -s "/c/Program Files/MATLAB/Single_R2015b/bin/mcc.bat" mcc
$ cd ~/tmp/magicSqr
$ mcc -m magicsquare.m
    # startup.m messages indicate that this launches Matlab
$ ./magicsquare.exe 5
Running C:\cygwin64\tmp\User.Name\mcrCache9.0\magics1\Users\User.Name\Documents\MATLAB\startup
m =  17  24   1   8  15
     23   5   7  14  16
      4   6  13  20  22
     10  12  19  21   3
     11  18  25   2   9
```

Both the directory specification `.` and the file extension `.exe`
are needed.

My next step was to push the full-blown `go.m` through the
process, see what breaks, and find the least onerous way to deal with
it.  By least onerous, I mean a strategy that requires fewest code
modifications so that I'm not maintaining separate code bases for
development versus for porting to the destination.

The `mcc` compilation worked: `mcc -m go.m`.  Running the `*.exe`
file, however, led to breakage at the very first executable statement:
`profile off`.  As I said, tactically recoding on an individual basis
is very unpalatable, so I searched for a way to identify all the files
to include when running `mcc`.  Two promising leads were [`inmem` and
`requiredFilesAndProducts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/identify-dependencies.html).
However, the above webpage also warns:

> Do not use the Dependency Report to determine which MATLAB code
>   files someone else needs to run a particular file. Instead use the
>   matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts function.

It *appears* that the *Dependency Report* to be avoided refers to the
*mfiles* output from `inmem`.  This is corroborated by examination of
said m-files -- the list is extremely long, and includes functions
that befuddle even Matlab's `which` command:

```
>> which matricize
'matricize' not found.
```

The only other candidate for identifying m-files to include is the
*fList* output from `requiredFilesAndProducts`.  It seems to include
all the methods for my custom classes, as well all invoked m-files
residing in `c:\Users\User.Name\Documents\MATLAB\` (the only
custom folder in my path).  However, it certainly does not cover the
`profile` command that underlies the aforementioned error.

What is the best way to identify all the m-files and/or folders
thereof for `mcc`?  Is it reasonable to then treat any remaining
error-causing statements using conditional execution, e.g., `if
~isdeployed; <...problematic statements...>; end`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer to the list on the documentation page here regarding information on unsupported functions to be compiled with MATLAB Compiler and MATLAB Compiler SDK products:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/unsupported-functions.html

This page below also shows the compatibility with MATLAB Compiler with each individual toolboxes:
https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/supported/compiler_support.html

Comment: Thank you so much!  So far, everything works!  (Though for the acid test, I have to try the process on a machine that doesn't have access to Matlab). **VERY IMPORTANTLY** (to me), R2015b's `mcc` finds all the dependencies for me, so I *only* need to issue `mcc -m go.m`.  No need to list all the m-files invoked when `go.m` runs, either my own m-files or TMW functions.